# Does unlocalizing a component destroy history?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

In our `030- content Spanish` publication, we had a bunch of components localized and their Spanish content was used. Later, those same components were unlocalized.

Is there a way to retrieve the Spanish content from history? The history is now showing the history of the root component from the `020-content`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you unlocalize a Component, the local version will be deleted. It's a permanent operation that can't be rolled back.

Comment: This is also why the Content Manager Explorer will warn you that "If you unlocalize, you will lose all changes. Are you sure you want to unlocalize?"

Answer (score 5):

As Frank suggested, it is permanent operation that can't be rolled back. The only option is to use old database if you got backup somewhere.

You may use old database backup on dev/test Tridion (if available) and can use content porter or manual copying from one that Tridion instance to another one.

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained, that localization history is gone except in other environments or database copies (this is what makes *template* localization tricky).

On the delivery end, if you haven't republished or unpublished, your rendered component presentations (not exactly your content) may still be on your content delivery servers on the file system or as configured in the storage configuration (broker database).

On the business side, your authors likely (hopefully) have the correct translated copy.

Consider training authors or adjusting localization and read folder permissions to only the authors responsible for translation for those publications.